# RSA hardware support in linux async crypto API?

Tags: api, asynchronous, cryptography, rsa

Does linux kernel's async crypto API support RSA operations? I mean can my driver utilize my RSA crypto hardware (assuming I have driver for the RSA hardware) using linux's async crypto API?
I see async interface is present in kernel only for cipher (ablkcipher) and hash operations (ahash) and not able to locate the same support for RSA?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

http://lwn.net/Articles/226660/ has some more info, I would recommend you contact the developer. BTW, there was also a discussion about including RSA in the kernel as it could slow down the kernel too much.